# Htaccess is matching directories when a file with the same name exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my Apache server, I have the following structure:

```
/www
    .htaccess
    api.php
    index.php
```

My .htaccess is a very simple file that redirects all the traffic to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And my index.php file just prints whatever the path is:

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST['path']); ?>
```

So when I try to access to `web.com/test`, I get a web that outputs `Array ( [path] => test )`.

However, when I try to access `web.com/index` or `web.com/api`, it returns a 404 error. I have checked that this only happens when I try to access a route with the name of an existing file. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I have `MultiViews` enabled in apache2.conf file. From the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and **effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files**, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name.

So I just had to add `Options -MultiViews` either to my apache2.conf (server-wise) or to the .htaccess of my project (project-wise) to prevent that behaviour.